# sheets.add suddenly started giving error 1004 after working 7000 times

Tags: vba, excel

I have code that's supposed to open a text file of data, record certain values from it, record them, close it, and open the next file.  There is one file for every hour of every day of the year thus far, and in order to keep track of these worksheets, I've been renaming them.

I got to around the end of May when I got an error 1004 "Method 'Add' of object 'Sheets' failed", even though it's already worked roughly 7000 times.

The line in question reads:

```
Sheets.Add(Before:=Sheets(1)).Name = lm & " " & j & " Hour " & kk
```

What could be going wrong here?  I'm new to VBA, so it could easily be something I overlooked, but why only now is it bugging out?

(last semi-related note: just signed up to ask this question specifically; if I've posted anything incorrectly or in a bad format, I apologise!)

edit: in case it helps, the code upt o that point is:

```
For i = 1 To 12                                     'for all months
  For j = 1 To 31                                 'for all days
    For k = 0 To 23                             'for all hours
      Select Case i
        Case "1"
          mmm = "Jan"
          lm = "January"
        Case "2"
          mmm = "Feb"
          lm = "February"
        Case "3"
          mmm = "Mar"
          lm = "March"
        Case "4"
          mmm = "Apr"
          lm = "April"
        Case "5"
          mmm = "May"
          lm = "May"
        Case "6"
          mmm = "Jun"
          lm = "June"
        Case "7"
          mmm = "Jul"
          lm = "July"
        Case "8"
          mmm = "Aug"
          lm = "August"
        Case "9"
          mmm = "Sep"
          lm = "September"
        Case "10"
          mmm = "Oct"
          lm = "October"
        Case "11"
          mmm = "Nov"
          lm = "November"
        Case "12"
          mmm = "Dec"
          lm = "December"
      End Select

      If i < 10 Then
        ii = "0" & i
      Else
        ii = i
      End If
      If j < 10 Then
        jj = "0" & j
      Else
        jj = j
      End If
      If k < 10 Then
        kk = "0" & k
      Else
        kk = k
      End If

      Sheets.Add(Before:=Sheets(1)).Name = lm & " " & j & " Hour " & kk

 'the code after this just opens up the text file at a path determined by 
 'the month, day, and hour, sorts data.  then comes: 

      Sheets(1).Delete
    Next k
  Next j
Next i
```

Comment: lm is "May", j is 22, and kk is "02".  Every single sheet thus far has followed this format..

Comment: Can you post the whole code please? It sounds like a context issue whereby the right workbook isn't active or something.

Comment: Given that lm is "May", is it possible that this sheet already exists?

Comment: At the end of the code I delete the first sheet; prior to that I was running into memory issues.  The only sheet remaining is called "Results".

Comment: did you reach the max capacity for worksheets in a workbook?

Comment: At first, yeah, but I ran into problems in February when I did that.  Once I started deleting each sheet as I finished with it, I haven't heard from that error since.  Does a deleted sheet still hold memory somehow?

Comment: you can also reduce the `Select Case` with two statements. `mmm = Format(i & "/1/2016","mmm")` and `lm = Format(i & "/1/2016","mmmm")`

Comment: @ScottHoltzman - or `Format("1/" & i & "/2016","mmm")` etc if the OP lives in a civilised country that uses dd/mm/yyyy format dates!  ;)

Comment: FWIW - The code ran happily for me.  Is it possible that there is something in the code that does the actual processing of the data that might be making some other workbook the Active one?

Comment: can't you use the same sheet all the time by just clearing it (`Sheets(1).UsedRange.ClearContents`), filling&sorting it and, once you're done  with it, iterate with next one?

Comment: Since at each iteration you add a sheet then delete it, why dont you try to use the same sheet but with deleting its content and then filling it again with the new content? (EDIT, just noticed the same comment by  user3598756).

Comment: I don't think the other workbook is active, because the code still manages to input a new sheet, and then that becomes active - it's just renaming it that it's having trouble with.  As to just recyling one sheet...well, I dunno', maybe.  I will give it a shot.

Comment: If you watch the codenames of your sheets, you will find that as they are created and deleted, the codenames continue to increment.  When you hit something around 8 or 9 thousand, it thunders in.  I found this while developing a macro that reads about 2400 files, and creates a number of sheets.  After about 10 passes, it started to fail.  I had to close the codebook and open it again to reset the codename counter.  If anyone knows how to do it in code, I'd sure love to hear about it.

Comment: Not related to your issue, but not all months have 31 days.  You can use `If Month(DateSerial(Year(Now), i, j)) = i Then '...` to check if the day is valid for the month (yes, it works with leap years).

Comment: @Hrothgar - I've never tested that, so just did.  It fell over at `Sheet10915`, although I've no idea of the significance of the number.  https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/Excel-specifications-and-limits-1672b34d-7043-467e-8e27-269d656771c3#bmworksheetworkbook

Comment: Renaming the sheet worked.  Turns out there were other issues in the code, so my results are completely incorrect, but at least it runs.  Thanks everybody!